# compile C# solution into DLL for use in python

Tags: c#, python, xamarin, mono

I am trying to use a specific natural language processor I found written in C# within my python application.

According to past SO posts, it seems as straightforward as:

1. import compile DLL file
2. call methods/classes of C# file from within python script with an enclosing wrapper

I have downloaded mono-develop and xamarin studio, have read the docs and attempted to "build" the C# program off of the .sln file, but have not observed any dll file being created

What step or doc am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z.aspx

This link provided from MSDN shows how to compile DLLs. You use the developer command prompt which is installed when you install any version of Visual Studio.

From the link, here is an example format:

```
csc /target:library /out:MathLibrary.DLL Add.cs Mult.cs
```

Comment: for manually adding together two cs files it makes sense. this is a much larger build. is there a particular "source file" I can try to reference instead of each individual cs file?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, maybe another answer will be provided for you. But if it's a large build you really only have to write the statement once then save it in a text file and copy and paste it into the developer command prompt anytime you need to update the build. Just a suggestion. How many cs files are we talkin'?

Comment: Added note, you can build the string using C# using System.IO and grabbing all .CS files and probably even pass it to the developer command prompt.

Comment: 62mb with a pretty robust file structure. I imagine if you wanted to run this without a python script, there'd be some sort of central "build file". there's also a BuildShell.ps1 file, a sln file, and a build.xml file.

Comment: You can parse the xml of your sln file to get the list of csproj files and then locate your csproj files, parse the xml of those to get the cs files. Honestly, probably easier to add all cs files to the line of code in the answer unless you have an xml parsing tool.

Comment: That sounds super ugly. I'll research some more and see if I can arrive at another solution before throwing in the towel

Comment: If another solution was found, please post.

Comment: Negative. haven't found one yet. I'm emailing the original author of the package to see if there's another way

Answer (score 0):

You can build a solution with xbuild. check this out for more information: [Microsoft.Build](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/xbuild/)

or you can just download mono develop and open the solution with it and just click build. it would create the output dll file in the `bin` folder.